# On Rails, how to run a simple line using delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

For http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Let's say I just start a brand new Rails project and want the following to be run every 1 minute:

```
puts "Time is now #{Time.now}"
```

How would I add it to the project?

The README says:

```
class NewsletterJob < Struct.new(:text, :emails)
  def perform
    emails.each { |e| NewsletterMailer.deliver_text_to_email(text, e) }
  end    
end  

Delayed::Job.enqueue NewsletterJob.new('lorem ipsum...', Customers.find(:all).collect(&:email))
```

but where should you put this content?  Do you run it once to enqueue?  How do you set the start time and the frequency?

Comment: I would probably use jQuery for that in a time ajax call..i'm also curious if there's a rails way though.

Comment: i think this is a background process but not at the browser side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delayed_job is gem for background tasks. You need a scheduling tool for that. I recommend http://github.com/javan/whenever.

http://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling.html